# Hibernate: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

He all was faced with a problem, can't understand how to solve it.
Thank in advance.

Hibernate throws an exception:

A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: TagEntity.nodeTagEntityList

I have read similar questions here, but they are related to oneToMany collections clear problem, but it occurrs when I just try to findAll() all the NodeTagEntity.
I can't understand what leat to this exception, because NodeTagEntity is mapped identically in both places VaultNodeEntity and TagEntity. I thought that it can not be referenced in two entity simultaneously but when I comment out nodeTagEntityList from TagEntity - it works, but when from VaultNodeEntity it does not help.

database schema

[image]

TagEntity
[image]

VaultNodeEntity

[image]

NodeTagEntiy

[image]